# Remove last two characters in cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the following data in an excel file:

```
01-01-01
01-01-02
...
60-05-04/1
```

And so on. I want to remove the last two specific characters in a cell, since they are unwanted in the database. The characters are /1, /2, /3...

If I use find and replace, the data turns into a date format, and if I format it as text, it turns into 600504 or something else, depending on the data in the cell, and there are roughly 12k entries in the file, at least half of which have the unwanted suffix. I have no experience with excel or VB excel coding.

Comment: This is VBA not VB.NET

Comment: Turn it into text format first and then remove the characters. This way it won't convert to date.

Comment: How about using If(Len("stringcell")>8,left("stringcell",8),"stringcell") and then just copy paste that over

Comment: Peh, I did that, all the cells in the column are formatted to text already, it doesn't convert them to date, but rather converts them to a number (30-05-03/1 becomes 37771 somehow).
@luuklag Where do I put that? I have no experience in excel apart from basic functions.

Comment: just in a column next to it, and then replace "stringcell" with the cell the string is in.

Comment: @Elnherjar I bet the number 37771 is the number of days since 1901-01-01. Change the format on the cell to date and it will probably be correct.

Comment: Okay, that works, thank you, but how do I now save the data without the formula? If I directly copy and paste it, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Are the cells without the trailing `/n`, that you show in your example, already dates?  Or did you somehow manage to enter them without converting them?  If so, how?

Comment: It was not done by me, I just got the list and am supposed to remove all the trailing numbers, to prepare it into a format for database use.

Comment: So, *Are the cells without the trailing /n, that you show in your example, already dates?*  Or is it only the one's you convert that turn into dates?

Comment: You can probably copy and paste values. Right click and find the paste option.

Comment: They are not dates, neither are they formatted as dates, just standard formatting.
However, I did format the whole column as text, if I format them by hand, they do not change into dates. If I use find and replace, they change into dates.

@Andreas Thank you, I just had to find the right paste option, just so the values were pasted.

Comment: So long as all is text, you can probably use the `Data►Text to columns` wizard.  Select the column data; then split delimited on the `/`.  At the third step, select to format the main column as Text, and to skip the column after the `/`.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies, this now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you found your answer using TEXT to COLUMNS as mentioned in the comments, but you can also use this formula:

`=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1), A1)`

Which will remove the characters after "/" including the slash itself.

This one will remove the last two characters of any cell.

`=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)`

Answer (score 0):

Procedure removes "/1" - "/6" from column A.

```
  Sub Remove()

    Columns(1).Replace "/1", ""
    Columns(1).Replace "/2", ""
    Columns(1).Replace "/3", ""
    Columns(1).Replace "/4", ""
    Columns(1).Replace "/5", ""
    Columns(1).Replace "/6", ""

End Sub
```